# Reading Python Documentation for 3rd party modules

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc, imdbpy

I recently downloaded IMDbpy module.. 
When I do,

```
import imdb
help(imdb)
```

i dont get the full documentation.. I have to do

```
im = imdb.IMDb()
help(im)
```

to see the available methods. I dont like this console interface. Is there any better way of reading the doc. I mean all the doc related to **module imdb in one page.**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html)

```
pydoc -w imdb
```

This will generate imdb.html in the same directory.

---

`pydoc -p 9090` will start a HTTP server on port 9090, and you will be able to browse all documentation at http://localhost:9090/

Comment: I tried.. But, still I am not getting the methods of "im" in the doc html

Comment: I still didnt get the methods of "im" in the doc.. Why was the answer upvoted...?

Comment: what function you are not able to see in `pydoc -p` ? I can see company, person, movie, etc classes with all functions in it.

Comment: sorry, if this is silly.. But, I am still not seeing the method "ia.search_movie()" in the docs..

Comment: @Shadyabhi: the documentation for above method can be found at 'Parser(package) -> http(package)' or http://localhost:1234/imdb.parser.http.html (if your server is running). I have no idea why the documentation is there, but it is present :).

Comment: Oh. I got it.. pydoc can be used to see the full documentation. You just have to search for the proper place.. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

in [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) you could do

```
[1]: import os
[2]: os?

< get the full documentation here >

# or you could do it on specific functions 
[3]: os.uname
<built-in function>



[4]: os.uname?

< get the full documentation here >


# Incase of modules written in python, you could inspect source code by doing
[5]: import string
[6]: string??

< hows the source code of the module >

[7]: string.upper??

< shows the source code of the function >
```